# How to manually create socket errors - node websocket(ws)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) for websocket in my node application. I want to simulate the possible errors that the server can get. I don't want to modify the server code, so I am trying to do that from the client side.

When I am emitting an error from the client side, that error was coming to client error handler, not going to the server. How can I send the error to the server(not as a message, as error event), so that I can test the error handlers there?

This is what I tried,

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var server = //url
var myClient = new WebSocket(server);

myClient.on('open', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    sendError(myClient);
  }, 5000);
});

myClient.on('error', clientErrorHandler(){
  //client error handler
  //This is being executed when emitting error
})

myClient.on('close', closeS(){
  //to clear some data
})

function sendError(client){
  client.emit('error', new Error('ECONNRESET'));
}
```

When the error emitted , `clientErrorHandler` got executed. It is not going to server. But I want this to be handled by server's `error` handler. How can that be done?

Comment: you can use the `error` event from Websocket class when setting up `connection` event callback on server to handle new connections. But you won't get too much information anyways. As far I know there is no possible way for server to take any action when an error occurs on client side . Try using an small  client side Ajax fallback to communicate with server until Websocket connection is restored , socket.io solves this, you just need to specify it in configuration.

Comment: I don't think you can properly simulate a socket error on the server by initiating something from the client, other than a disconnect.  Socket errors on the server would be something that happened on the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the clarification :) I will emit the same error on server side to check it's behavior